# Tasks related to Care plans are visible in health cloud timeline but not the Events

Tags: health-cloud

I have created Timeline View Configurations record for both Task and Event with Patient Account Lookup as WhatID.

Once we apply the Care Plan Template to Patient, the respective tasks are created under Case (Care plan). i.e Task.WhatID -- Case ID and these tasks are visible in the Timeline view. (though the WhatId is CaseId and not the AccountId)

Whereas when I create a follow-up event for this Task, it creates a new Event under the same Case populates Event.WhatID to Case id, however, it does not reflect the Event in Timeline.

Firstly am not sure how Case related Tasks are visible in Timeline view. Are there any configurations to allow the same for Events without changing the What id of Case to Account?

Answer (score -1):

I do not quite understand what you are doing.

However, from my experience working with Tasks and Events, the issues I came up with had to do with the Activity object. Which is the father class of both of them.